# PostgreSQL detected deadlock error when create table partition

Tags: postgresql, deadlock

I am using PostgreSQL 10 new partition table feature. And I have a partitioned parent table looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE names (
    id integer,
    name varchar(64)
) PARTITION BY RANGE (id)
```

And I have many nodes creating partition table in parallel like this when loading the data into the database

```
CREATE TABLE names__139__119230558__120050888 PARTITION OF names
FOR VALUES FROM ('119230558') TO ('120050888')
```

Then somehow, `deadlock detected` error will raise like this

```
ERROR:  deadlock detected
DETAIL:  Process 7802 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 16401 of database 16390; blocked by process 7803.
    Process 7803 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 16401 of database 16390; blocked by process 7802.
    Process 7802: 
          CREATE TABLE names__139__119230558__120050888 PARTITION OF names
          FOR VALUES FROM ('119230558') TO ('120050888')
    Process 7803: 
          CREATE TABLE names__94__80601867__81503664 PARTITION OF names
          FOR VALUES FROM ('80601867') TO ('81503664')
```

Here's the odd part, not surprising, deadlock means two process waiting resource to be released by other processes while they are holding the resource required by each other, however, look at deadlock error closly

```
Process 7802 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 16401 of database 16390; blocked by process 7803.
Process 7803 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 16401 of database 16390; blocked by process 7802.
```

It's actually waiting for the same resource `relation 16401 of database 16390`, which is `names` parent partition table in this case. So the question is, how come a deadlock will be detected when two processes are actually acquiring the same resource? I thought the second process should wait for the first one to finish.

Comment: did you make any progress here?